# Insert JSON data from array in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, function

Here I have a `nArray` function which return me a `bigArray` - JSON so with nArray function I create a bigArray objects

Example:

```
Array[5]
0: Object
1: Object
     DISTANCE_FROM_PREVIOUS_OBJECT_LOCATION: 2.087970147789207
     lat: "48.866588"
     leftPosition: 183
     lng: "2.309037999999987"
     topPosition: 57
        __proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

As you can see I have Objetcs in bigArray that contain: lat,left,lng,top and DISTANCE_

Now I need with function `updateTooltipContent` to get DISTANCE from OBJECT where is latt=lat:

```
function updateTooltipContent() {
    var latt = $(this).attr("lat");

    //FIND IN WHICH OBJECT IS latt = lat and from that OBJECT[i] get DISTANCE_ ...

      return "Distance is" + DISTANCE_FROM_PREVIOUS_LOCATION;
    }
});
```

Is there any way to do that? So I need to call function `nArray` which will create bigArray and from thee find in which objet is latt = lat and get from that OBJECT[i] DISTANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `nArray` function returns the bigArray you just need to loop over it and at each iteration check if `latt == lat`.

```
var bigArray = nArray();
var distance = 0.00;

for(var x = 0; x < bigArray.length; x++)
{
    if(bigArray[x].lat == latt)
    {
        distance = bigArray[x].DISTANCE_FROM_PREVIOUS_OBJECT_LOCATION;
        break; // no point doing anymore loops as we've found the answer
    }        
}
```

Might need to use the parseFloat function in js depending on how you are dealing with the numbers.

Comment: Just wrap the parseFloat function around bigArray[x].lat. Check this link for more examples of its use  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: yes but whats look like in my example? THANKS very much, I will see is this working for me.